# Struct Padding Optimization in C

Tags: c, gcc, struct, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct X
{
    short s; 
    int i; 
    char c;
};

struct Y
{
    int i;
    char c;
    short s;
};

struct Z
{
    int   i;
    short s;
    char  c;
};

int main() {
    printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", sizeof(struct X), sizeof(struct Y), sizeof(struct Z));
    return 0;
}
```

The above [code](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-s096-introduction-to-c-and-c-january-iap-2013/pages/lectures-and-assignments/data-structures-debugging/) returns

```
12 8 8
```

demonstrating that a structure's size depends on the order its members are declared.
Are there any compiler settings to optimally reorder these declarations (for minimum struct size)? What are some general rules of practice that ensure optimal padding as projects scale?

Comment: "*demonstrating that a structure's alignment depends on the order its members are declared*" -- no, you have shown that a structure's ***size*** can vary with the order of its members.  That's typically related to the members alignment requirements, but you haven;t shown anything about the structures' alignment requirements.

Comment: Re "*demonstrating that a structure's alignment depends on the order its members are declared*" No, you haven't. You demonstrated the size of depends on the order. In fact, the alignment restriction of the structure is quite unlikely to depend on the order. /// "Re "*that ensure optimal alignment*", You mean "that ensures minimal padding"?

Comment: if the size has changed (with all same data), does that not imply a change in alignment? regardless, @ikegami yes my question is about optimizing padding length (i.e, minimizing).

Comment: so in general, its best to just use a 'greedy pseudo-algorithm' for placement?

Comment: No, @Shea, a size difference does not necessarily imply a difference in alignment requirement.  Most often, the alignment requirement of a structure matches that of its most strictly aligned member, regardless of member order.  And even for numeric types, alignment requirement is not necessarily the same as size.

Comment: i misunderstood how to use the term 'alignment requirement' - question edited accordingly. For any other newbies, I needed an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15834388/22673230) for the meaning of 'most strictly aligned' in this context. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @ikegami: Re “Order the fields in order of descending size”: No, putting a large structure member with a low alignment requirement and a size that is an odd multiple of its alignment requirement before a smaller member with a larger requirement will not minimize structure size. Even for scalar members, that is not a universally correct algorithm. Ordering by descending alignment requirement is.

Comment: @ikegami: No, they are not the same, as my example with a structure demonstrates. Even if all scalar objects have alignment requirements equal to their size, structures do not, generally, and C implementations must support structures (and arrays). There is no reason to tell people to sort by size. The correct algorithm is to sort by alignment requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any compiler settings to optimally reorder these declarations (for minimum struct size)?

No.  C allows programs to rely on and be sensitive to structure member order. Compilers are not free to reorder structure members.

> What are some general rules of practice that ensure optimal alignment

Generally speaking, you can minimize the padding in structure layouts by ordering members by decreasing alignment requirement.

Many compilers also provide extensions that enable you reduce or eliminate structure padding at the possible cost of reduced performance arising from misaligned access to members.  These extensions are not portable across compilers, however, and they are moot on platforms where misaligned access produces hard errors instead of mere performance penalties.

Comment: Re "*C allows programs to rely on and be sensitive to structure member order.*", This allows structures to be extended while retaining backwards compatibility in an ABI. /// This also allows creating different structures with common beginnings e.g. for polymorphism.